# Problem of grant select on role to existing user

Tags: postgresql

I've run the following:

`GRANT select ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema1 TO role1`

But the user under role1 still cannot select on table under schema1 , is it because of only new user will have the permission?

I've also try

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema1 GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO role1`

Then say I login with user1 that is belong to role1 ( in the past I create that user1 with "CREATE user user1 WITH PASSWORD abc IN GROUP role1" ) . running `select * from schema1.tab1 limit 1` give permission deny

But it is the same, cannot select the table, not sure what is the solution?

BTW, role1 is created with following SQL:

```
CREATE GROUP role1;
GRANT USAGE on SCHEMA schema0 TO role1;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema0 TO role1;
```

Where `select rolinherit from pg_roles where rolname='role1'` return true, I believe permission should inherited by user under that role

The user under the role is in upper case... look like that causing some problem

Comment: What do you mean by "the user under role1"? What permissions do they have on the database and schema? Please show us your complete setup (to make a [mcve]) and the exact error message.

Comment: Per [ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html): *ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES allows you to set the privileges that will be applied to objects created in the future. (It does not affect privileges assigned to already-existing objects.)*

Comment: Hi this is the example:

```GRANT select ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema1 TO role1```

. Then there are user1 that is belong to role1 ( in the past I create that user1 with ```"CREATE user user1 WITH PASSWORD abc IN GROUP role1"``` )

. When I login as user1, ```select * from schema1.tab1 limit 1``` give permission deny

Comment: Hi I only need object created in the past have access, not sure why it don't give

Comment: @carfield Does `role1` have the `NOINHERIT` attribute by any chance? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-membership.html

Comment: Add your further explanation as text update to question. This sort of information shpuld not be in the comments.

Comment: sure, just update the question, thanks for remind

Comment: "*The user under the role is in upper case... look like that causing some problem*" - yes, like any identifier you will need to quote user/role names (with `"`) so that they keep their casing and do not get canonicalised. You may inadvertently have created multiple roles with similar but different names.

Answer (score -4):

It is not the issue of new users getting access. The SELECT privilege should be granted to role1 on all tables in schema1 by the GRANT and ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES lines you supplied.
Verify that the user is actually a part of role1 by running this command.

```
SELECT rolname FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'your_username';
```

Now run this query to verify that the role that received the permissions owns the schema1 and the tables within it.

```
SELECT nspname, relname, relkind, rolname
FROM pg_class c
JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
JOIN pg_roles r ON r.oid = c.relowner
WHERE nspname = 'schema1';
```

Now chevck if the owner is not role1 then use ALTER SCHEMA and ALTER TABLE procedures to change the ownership to role1.

Make sure that schema1 is properly included in the search route for your user. The order in which PostgreSQL searches for objects like schemas or tables is determined by the search path. This command will check your current search path  and makes sure that PostgreSQL looks in schema1 for tables first.

```
SHOW search_path TO schema1, public;
```

If the issue persists, it can be a configuration issue or a more serious database problem. If so, look through the PostgreSQL server logs for any error warnings.

hope it works :)

Comment: 1) This looks like a ChatGPT answer. If for no other reason then:  2) This `SELECT rolname FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'your_username';` is not going to tell you whether `'your_username` is part of `role1`. 3) This `SELECT nspname, relname, relkind,  ...` is not going to show schema ownership and 4) This `SHOW search_path TO schema1, public;` is wrong and the `search_path` is not the problem. That would manifest as a different error.

Comment: Thanks, actually for ```SELECT rolname FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'your_username';``` , my PostgreSQL say no column with that name